# Why does sbt 1.02 not suppress debug logging messages?

Tags: sbt

Install details:

- SBT 1.02
- Scala 2.12.3
- Java 8
- Ubuntu Linux 16.04 on a ThinkPad & Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.6)

Steps I took:

1. Installed SBT on both Linux and Mac using instructions here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/
2. Created the Hello World example.
3. Tried to run the sample program, both within SBT and on the bash command line.
4. Observed that regardless of what settings I tried, I would still see the debug messages:

Here's a sample:

```
Osiris:hello Noel$ sbt
[info] Loading project definition from 
/Users/Noel/src/scala/sandbox/hello/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to Hello (in build 
file:/Users/Noel/src/scala/sandbox/hello/)
[info] sbt server started at 127.0.0.1:5256
sbt:Hello> logLevel
[info] warn
sbt:Hello> run
[info] Running example.Hello 
hello
[debug] Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
[debug]   Classpath:
[debug]     <abbreviated>.../hello_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[debug]     <abbreviated>.../scala-library.jar
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main-0 to terminate.
[debug]     Thread run-main-0 exited.
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
[debug] Exited with code 0
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 15, 2017 9:44:13 PM
sbt:Hello>
```

What I tried:

1. From the command line: 
   sbt warn run
2. From within SBT: 
   warn
   run
3. Modify build.sbt to contain the line:
   logLevel := Level.Warn

Here is what build.sbt looks like:

```
import Dependencies._

logLevel := Level.Warn

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    )),
    name := "Hello",
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

I've also searched on this forum, but this question was asked 4 years ago and those answers don't work for me.  What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in sbt 1.0.1 and 1.0.2. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3655